# Get rows from database

Tags: php, sql, database, get

I have a connection where i want to get some data from my database.
I have inserted some data but now i want to retreive it but i get NULL.

I have no idea why.

```
<?php
require "connect.php";      
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltemperature ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($results);
$t = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $weather[] = array(
                    $row["time"], 
                    $row["inside_temperature"] 
                );  
    echo $row["time"];
    echo $row["inside_temperature"];
}
$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you __understand__ that `$result` and `$results` are __different__ variables?

Comment: @u_mulder We all make simple mistakes.  There's no need to be rude about it.  `var_dump` on `$result` won't provide any useful information anyway.

Comment: @MattS now look into comment to an answer. Is it useful? No?

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, totally forgot that.

Comment: Are you using a prepared statement for this? Perhaps you need http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php (one of the mysqli nuisances)

Answer (score 0):

check `var_dump($results);` , it looks like it should be `var_dump($result);` 
otherwise you should check `$result->num_rows()` first to know if there is any row available.

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Remove the 'LIMIT 1' from the SQL statement, I think you need to go through PHP MYSQL Programming tutorials.

Comment: The LIMIT 1 is a test. In the end I want the last 15 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to check your query in phpmyadmin query is working or not. If working you should try to `var_dump($result);` and after

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> time: ". $row["time"]. " - inside_temperature: ". $row["inside_temperature"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```